# Display: flex from display: none in breakpoint not working in safari on OSX

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Given the following HTML and CSS, the myLinks div is hidden on screens below 1025px and displays as a flexbox on screens above 1025px. The div remains hidden in Safari.

```css
#myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.menu-link {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  #myLinks {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    top: 10%;
    right: 0;
    height: 85vh;
    max-height: 85%;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myLinks" class="menu-link"></div>
```

What's really strange is I just noticed the elements are on the page, but aren't being rendered. I'm able to click on them, but I can't see them. Changing z-index to 999 doesn't resolve the issue

Edit: here's a fully built example, I don't think any of the children are causing #myLinks to be hidden because a .menu-card element removed from #myLinks is displayed and works normally, but maybe something in here doesn't play well with something in myLinks...

Run in full page

```css
#myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.menu-link { 
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.menu-card {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.card-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}

/*Style navigation menu images*/
.menu-icon {
    display: block;
    max-width: 15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Style navigation menu links */
#myLinks a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
#myLinks {
        background-color: transparent;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: fixed;
        width: 300px;
        top: 10%;
        right: 0;
        height: 85vh;
        max-height: 85%;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

.menu-card a {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        right: 20%;
        max-height: 55%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(148, 181, 201);
        background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
        transition: all 0.8s;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .card-text {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 0;
        top: 6%;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 125%;
        opacity: 0;
        color: #5DCA31;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
        margin: 0;
        border-color: rgb(148, 181, 201);
        border-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 90px;
        transition: all 0.8s;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .menu-card:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.8s;
    }

    .menu-card:hover .menu-icon {
        right: 5%;
    }

    .menu-card:hover .card-text {
        opacity: 1;
        padding-left: 10%;
        max-height: 65%;
        width: 100%;
        border-width: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: rgb(148, 181, 201);
        background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
        padding-right: 100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        transition: background-color 0.8s, border-width 0.8s, max-width 0.8s;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myLinks" class="menu-link">
  <div class="menu-card">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="menu-icon" src="https://nuclearterrortoday.org/img/home.jpg">
          <p class="card-text"  id="home">Home</p>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some more of your `CSS` used. I mean can you also add in your question the relevant `CSS` for `menu-link` class? You could be a bit more specific on your media query by using `#myLinks.menu-link` for example...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    #myLinks {
        /* all the styles */
    }
}
```

Or just

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    #myLinks {
        /* all the styles */
    }
}
```

The keyword ‘only’ hides style sheets from older user agents.
Hope this helps!